# Acces Denied on Filer

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

If I run `remove-Item \\filer\path\to\file.txt` in Powershell Console, it works.

But if I run the same command in a Script that is Scheduled with highest elevation it gives an Access Denied back.

What are the differences that cause this?
How can I fix this?

Comment: This sort of issue is almost always a rights problem. The account that is running the scheduled task (probably System) cannot see the share.

Comment: It might be that the file is in use when the task tries to remove it. But I agree most likely it's permission problem.